# Embedding text on an opaque plane in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

A simplified specification of what I am trying to accomplish would be to construct a cube each face with a different color and each face having a text label that can be seen only when viewing from the front direction of the face (I do not want the labels on the back and side faces to show through the cube.)  I also want the labels to be in the plane of the face and to remain in the plane of the face as I rotate the cube.

Comment: Like a `Texture[]`? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html

Comment: @belisarius I guess that could work for me. I  do not know how to create the textures on the fly as color and text will be variable in what I want to actually do. I will try to look into Texture and any hints would be appreciated! I hoped I could just use Text and perhaps Glow for the colors in some way.

Comment: Closely [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27566/5478)

Comment: [some fun answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154079/add-text-to-faces-of-polyhedron) to a similar question

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding

Answer (score 4):

```
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  Tuples[{0, 1}, 3],
   MapThread[
    {Texture[
       Graphics[ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]], Background -> #3]],
     Polygon[#2, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]} &,
    {Characters["ABCDEF"],
     {{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 
       3, 4}, {8, 4, 2, 6}},
     Table[Hue[i/6], {i, 6}]}
    ]
   ],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this extracts a [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html) from the list of [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) returned by [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImportString.html) (see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/563/undocumented-syntax-of-filledcurve)):

```
ImportString[ExportString[#1, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: +1 Very clean. The use to which `Tuples` was put was especially clever!

Answer (score 0):

```
vtc    =  {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
coords = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 
          {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
          {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, 
          {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
          {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, 
          {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}};

tt = Table[Texture@Image[Rasterize@Style[RandomInteger@10, 30]], {i, 6}];
Graphics3D[Table[{tt[[i]], Polygon[coords[[i]],
           VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]}, {i, 6}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the example. As posted vtc is not defined, but I am beginning to get the idea anyway.

Comment: @RonBurns Sorry, I forgot to paste it. Corrected