# How to improve visibility of surfaces with opacity?

Tags: graphics3d

Consider this example

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.5],
 Blue,  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1/3}],
 Green, Cuboid[{0, 0, 1/3}, {1, 1, 2/3}],
 Red,   Cuboid[{0, 0, 2/3}, {1, 1, 1}],
 Gray, Opacity[1], Sphere[{1/2, 1/2, #/3 - 1/6}, 0.1] & /@ {1, 2, 3}},
Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

For the green box, the edges and the surfaces in the back are also quite visible. For blue and red boxes the contrast is much smaller. How to improve it such a way that the edges would be visible from the difference in colour and also make the balls inside visible?

One possible way can be using an extra layer with slightly different opacity

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.5],
  Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1/3}],
  Green, Cuboid[{0, 0, 1/3}, {1, 1, 2/3}],
  Red, Cuboid[{0, 0, 2/3}, {1, 1, 1}],
 Opacity[0.6],
  Blue, Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
  Red, Polygon[{{0, 0, 2/3}, {0, 1, 2/3}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
 Gray, Opacity[1], Sphere[{1/2, 1/2, #/3 - 1/6}, 0.1] & /@ {1, 2, 3}},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

For a lot of boxes, it does not seem to be a good option.

Comment: Why not just adjust the opacity of each layer "by eye"?  (Create a Manipulate to help you along.)  My general principle in cases such as yours is to set the opacity high (0.9) for objects that obscure no others, and incrementally lower for other layers, and low (0.2) for objects that are not obscured by others.  You might try `EdgeForm[Orange]` too.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG.Stork. I have to keep `Opacity`<=0.5, because I have to put some sticks and balls inside the boxes. I prefer the edges free from lines - it looks better. The problem is only with few specific colours. I was wondering if it can be fixed by adjusting the `Lighting` and shadow.

Comment: I urge you to put the sticks into your figure here, so we know the TRUE problem you're solving.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. I modified my question. The objective is to make both the surfaces of the boxes and the object inside visible.

Comment: (1) The `Lighting -> "Neutral"` option in `Graphics3D` can help equalize variations in shading between different colours. (2) You could use something like `FaceForm[Opacity[0.3], Opacity[0.7]]` to make the front faces more transparent than the back ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (tedious) way is to define a box with different `Opacity` for different surfaces.

```
opqbox[{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}, {d_, u_, l_, r_, b_, f_}] := {EdgeForm[None],
           Opacity[b], Polygon[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}, {x1, y2, z1}}],
           Opacity[u], Polygon[{{x1, y1, z2}, {x2, y1, z2}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x1, y2, z2}}],
           Opacity[r], Polygon[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y1, z1}, {x2, y1, z2}, {x1, y1, z2}}],
           Opacity[l], Polygon[{{x1, y2, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x1, y2, z2}}],
           Opacity[o], Polygon[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x1, y2, z1}, {x1, y2, z2}, {x1, y1, z2}}],
           Opacity[f], Polygon[{{x2, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x2, y1, z2}}]}


opc={0.5,0.15,0.35,0.20,0.25,0.25};
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],Opacity[0.5],
            Blue,opqbox[{0,0,0},{1,1,1/3},opc],
            Green,opqbox[{0,0,1/3},{1,1,2/3},opc],
            Red,opqbox[{0,0,2/3},{1,1,1},opc],
          Gray,Opacity[1],Sphere[{1/2,1/2,#/3-1/6},0.1]&/@{1,2,3}},
Boxed->False]
```

[image]

`d, u, l, r, b, f` are the `Opacity` for down, up, left, right, back and front face.

[image]

This cube is made by the method suggested by Michael E2 [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28543/8070).