# Basic 3D Graphics Question

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

This is probably a very basic question, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. I am trying to create a filled 3D space in the region

$\qquad 0.1 < x < 9.2,\ 0.026 < y < 28.97,\ 0 < z < 5.23$

but haven't been able to manage it yet.

Any help someone would have to offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `Cuboid` and `Graphics3D`.

Comment: Or `Raster3D` if you want the coloration to vary over the space.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165409/8070) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the way you specifying your region, you might want an alternative to `Graphics3D` primitives approach (`Cuboid` would be the simples in your case). Specify:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[.1<x<9.2 && .026<y<28.97 && 0<z<5.23, {x, y, z}]
```

Then use

```
Region[reg]
```

[image]

or alternatively

```
RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

For both functions `RegionPlot3D` and `Region` you should explore various options of visual styling. This is more complex than `Graphics3D` but advantage is this can go to more complex regions for which there is no `Graphics3D` primitives, for example:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[4 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 9, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0.1, 0.026, 0}, {9.2, 28.97, 5.23}]]
```