# Drawing text on Cuboid's Plane

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, text

I am trying to draw a Text which will stick to a Cuboid's plane. But the text is showing up even when I rotate the cube. Also the text is not sticked on a fixed position on that plane.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.95], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}]},Text["Surface", {0, 1, 1}]}]]
```

This is what I get after rotating the cube

[image: On Plane]
[image: Text dislocated]
[image: Text shows up in other planes]

How can I stick the text on a plane ? So that when I rotate the cube The text will automatically shear or disappear or look like a mirror image from its opposite plane ? As I am drawing many such small cubes and texts are serving as labels of those cubes, I need a fast and small solution.

Comment: You can use `Texture`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27566/5478

Comment: Another way: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28543/4999